# Command-line application for converting SVG to PNG on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, command-line, png, svg

Are there any command-line programs that can convert an SVG to PNG that run on macOS?

Comment: I found a way if you have Google Chrome... and no need to install any other things: http://superuser.com/questions/134679/command-line-application-for-converting-svg-to-png-on-mac-os-x/1036841#1036841

Comment: https://cairosvg.org/  works for python3 and seems to have no issue. `pip3 install cairosvg`

Answer (score 347, accepted):

Or without installing anything:

```
qlmanage -t -s 1000 -o . picture.svg
```

It will produce picture.svg.png that is 1000 pixels wide.

I have tested it only on OS X 10.6.3.

Comment: Unfortunately this clips images to a square.

Comment: Ah, `qlmanage -t` gives the thumbnail used by Quick Look (in Finder, etc). Clever idea. Unfortunately, these thumbnails can be buggy, especially when there's text involved.

Comment: This produces images with the svg file in the 1st quadrant.  Doesn't auto crop.  Trying to convert files from noun project - wish this worked.

Comment: It will also not scale down the image to fit everything within the specified width.

Comment: One other note is that it did not preserve the transparent background of my image... still quite handy and worked for me otherwise! :)

Comment: Any way to do this without it adding a white background?

Comment: This solution fails to take transparency into account. The tool `rsvg-convert` in @ahti's answer worked out before for me.

Comment: the -s option takes dimensions in the form "-s 1920x1080" so you can specify the precise dimensions you want. It seems like the image is not clipped if you specify full dimensions.

Comment: is there any way to tell qlmanage to use a specific density? man revealed nothing.

Comment: Putting both width and height parameters after the `-s` option didn't work for me. Still crops it to a square. Very frustrating!

Comment: transparency doesn't seem to work

Comment: Never heard of this tool. Can one comment on this please? (It worked)

Comment: If the SVG has a border this tool will correctly capture the top and left border but will cut off the right side and bottom of the image.

Answer (score 229):

I found that for me the best tool for the job is `rsvg-convert`.

It can be [found in brew](https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/librsvg) with `brew install librsvg` and is used like this:

```
rsvg-convert -h 32 icon.svg > icon-32.png
```

This example creates a 32px high png. The width is determined automatically.

Comment: This is the only one that worked for me on Mavericks and https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Windows_logo_-_2012_derivative.svg

Comment: Actually this one worked, while ImageMagick's `convert` issued errors and failed to covert a complex SVG

Comment: This is by far the best solution I've found for OS X Yosemite +1!

Comment: This failed for some of my SVGs, strangely. The `qlmanage` answer worked for all of them but put a white background, which I don't want.

Comment: If some of your SVGs don't work with this (and you are sure the files are not faulty), consider filing a bug with the librsvg project (https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/LibRsvg)

Comment: This answer worked for me on OS X 10.10, while the imagemagick answer didn't.

Comment: @sudo Try normalizing the SVGs using `hxnormalize` from `brew install html-xml-utils`.

Comment: The best solution because it uses a very good rasterizer in terms of resolution.

Comment: And remember automator is your friend if you have to do a whole bunch: ask for finder items, run shell script passing input as argument, then something like ```PATH=/usr/local/bin:/bin export PATH
for filename in "$@"
do
  finalFilename="${filename%.svg}.png"
  rsvg-convert -h 300 "$filename" > "$finalFilename"
done```

Comment: `rsvg-convert` has parameters `-d (x-dpi)` and `-p (y-dpi)`, to  allow user to control density during export

Comment: With `rsvg-convert`, the resulting .png had the right dimensions, but the image came out all black instead of the original colors. With `qlmanage` the image is cropped to a square. Still searching for a solution :-(

Comment: Where the SVG has overlapping semi-transparent elements, these are not rendered correctly. FWIW Affinity Photo has the same problem.

Comment: Batch converting like this `find . -type f -name "*.svg" -exec bash -c 'rsvg-convert -h 800 "$0" > "$0".png' {} \;`

Comment: `rsvg-convert` will not trim blank around png file. use `convert image.png -trim output.png` to trim them.

Comment: As of April 2020, rsvg-convert has no current release via homebrew.

Comment: @Tom what do you base that on? The latest available version is 2.48.3 (according to https://download.gnome.org/sources/librsvg/2.48/), which has been available in brew since the 10th of April, one day after it was released (https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/pull/52815).

Comment: @Ahti You're correct! I failed to note the proper package name in your answer. Your instructions work perfectly when followed correctly, and rsvg-convert works like a charm. I'm sorry for the trouble.

Comment: This works on OS X Mojave with no cropping. It also outputs all of used canvas and does auto height/width trimming. I find this useful to export large canvas drawings as SVG over PNG/PDF from iPad apps, e.g., Concepts app which otherwise crash exporting larger drawings as PNG/PDF.

Comment: Installation is failing for me with `Error: An exception occurred within a child process:
  FormulaUnavailableError: No available formula with the name "/usr/local/opt/python@2/.brew/python@2.rb"`

Comment: The only one that worked for me on macOS Monterey without getting trash output.

Comment: Best solution, this should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 73):

[ImageMagick](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/download.php#macosx) is an *extremely* versatile command-line image editor, which would probably rival Photoshop if it had, you know, a GUI. But who needs those anyways. :P

Something like the following would convert a .svg to .png, after installation:

```
$ convert picture.svg picture.png
```

The original .svg isn't deleted.

Comment: It *sort of* has a GUI, in `display`.

Comment: When I installed ImageMagick with Fink, I couldn't convert svg to png - there were some errors. It turned out that I needed to install librsvg2-bin as well.

Comment: If librsvg2-bin isn't installed (like on OS X) this will fail. Couldn't find a way to get that installed on OS X.

Comment: This won't work well if you want to resize the SVG as it generates blurry images.

Comment: It doesn't convert all SVG files correctly either; at least qlmanage got all the parts of the image.

Comment: Even using -density the export is weird. I thought my SVG were of poor quality (all circles were in fact polygons) using rsvg-convert worked much better!

Comment: This is the only one that works for all SVGs for me. The quality seems nice, unless I'm missing something. I used -density 600.

Comment: For an 800kb SVG file, imagemagick has already used 15 minutes of CPU time and is still going. This is not ideal. I usually like using ImageMagick.

Comment: I've never had issues with imagemagick on linux systems, but on mac it creates blurry or blank output

Comment: Gradients don't work correctly.

Comment: this doesn't seem to generate transparent backgrounds for me. everything is white. are there some options?

Comment: imagmagick's convert seems to just use rsvg-convert (librsvg2-bin) under the hood.

Comment: I was excited to use imagemagick for this, but it did not capture all the elements of my SVG in the output :/

Comment: does not work if you need transparency or gradients. Issue is described here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/28332339/804521

Answer (score 42):

[Inkscape](http://inkscape.org/download/) with it's Commandline-Interface produces the best results for me:

Install Inkscape:

```
brew install inkscape
```

Convert test.svg to output.png with a width of 1024 (keep aspect ratio):

```
/Applications/Inkscape.app/Contents/MacOS/inkscape --export-type png --export-filename output.png -w 1024 test.svg
```

OLD ANSWER (doesn't work anymore with latest inkscape):

```
/Applications/Inkscape.app/Contents/Resources/bin/inkscape --export-png output.png -w 1024 -h 768 input.svg*
```

Comment: this is working for me! -  ihave a bigger SVG created with Inkscape

Comment: This is the only method that rendered my hand-written svg correctly

Comment: Convert does not generate good PNG files from SVG. Using Inkscape is the best way I have found so far.

Comment: This works for me, but creates extremely blurry files.

Comment: I had a problem to find files so run it as `inkscape $(pwd)/logo.svg --export-png $(pwd)/logo.png`

Comment: @Marcin @ol_v_er Add e.g. `--export-dpi 600` to get higher quality

Comment: `inkscape --export-type="png" $(ls -q)` worked like Magic to export all SVG files in my directory to PNG files, with good quality!

Comment: dont work for me.

Answer (score 33):

OK, I found a simple way to do it on the Mac if you have Google Chrome.

(and this works even if it is to convert a `webp` file in Chrome to `png` or `jpg`)

In one sentence, it is to see the `svg` image in a webpage (must be in an `html` file), right click on image and choose "Copy Image" and paste to the Preview app.

Steps:

1. Download or have the `svg` file in your hard drive, say, `somefile.svg`
2. Now, in the same folder, just make an html file `tmp.html` that contains this line: `<img src="somefile.svg">`
3. Now, open that html file in Google Chrome
4. You should see the image.  Now just right click on the image and choose "Copy Image"
5. Go to Mac's Preview App, and choose, `"File -> New from Clipboard"`
6. Now `File -> Save` the file and you have the `png` file. (or other file types).

This is tested on the current Chrome (version 48.0) on Mac OS X El Capitan.

**Update**: I am not sure whether it is due to some restriction imposed by Google Chrome. I just try an SVG file using Chrome 58.0, and I get a tiny image from the method above. If you see this case too, you can also use

```
<img src="somefile.svg" style="height: 82vh; margin-top: 9vh; margin-left: 9vh">
```

or if you want more margin, use:

```
<img src="somefile.svg" style="height: 64vh; margin-top: 18vh; margin-left: 18vh">
```

and you will have an image on screen good enough for you to do a screenshot -- using <kbd>Cmd</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>4</kbd> or <kbd>Cmd</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>3</kbd> on the Mac, for example. Make sure you resize your Chrome window to the maximum allowed on the screen first.

Comment: Smart solution!

Comment: This actually produces the best results for me since it renders exactly the same as the browser.

Comment: the resulting image was very poor resolution for me

Comment: Ingenious :) but for very large SVGs, the resolution of the resulting image is too low, as @Michael mentioned.

Answer (score 11):

I have made [svgexport](https://github.com/shakiba/svgexport) using node/npm for this, it is cross-platform and can be as simple as:

```
svgexport input.svg output.png
```

Comment: This was the easiest one to use and remember by far. Also, the only one that produced a correct result in my case.

Comment: resulting resolution wasn't great for me.

Answer (score 7):

If you want to do many at once, you can:

`mogrify -format png *.svg`

There are options to resize etc on the fly, too..

Comment: `mogrify` is also par of ImageMagick.

Comment: Works great, but brutally slow.

Comment: -1? Someone thinks this isn't helpful? What's the error?

Comment: I'm not the one who downvoted, but worth noting is that ImageMagick stupidly converts svg to a raster image of arbitrary size before resizing,  resulting in blurry output.

Comment: Installing inkscape first (and getting it on the path) can improve conversion results.

Answer (score 7):

Yet another method without installing anything. Not in command line though.

1. Open the .svg file in Safari.
2. Press alt-command-i to open the inspector.
3. Right-click on the `<svg>` tag, select "Capture Screenshot". (Note that you mustn't zoom in the image.)

P.S. To enlarge the .svg image if it's too small, try opening the .svg file in text editor and append `0` to every number except in the meta-attribute. This can be done by a global regex substitution from `(\d+)` to `$10`, where `$1` is the placeholder for back reference, for example.

Comment: You probably should mention that this is almost the same as  [太極者無極而生’s answer](https://superuser.com/q/134679/150988#134679).

Comment: just fyi: using brave, i was able to zoom in fine and get a better resolution "screenshot"

Comment: Best and fastest one __with transparency__

Answer (score 5):

This is what I used:

`brew install imagemagick --with-librsvg`

Then run the following commands:

`find . -type f -name "*.svg" -exec bash -c 'convert $0 $0.png' {} \;
rename 's/svg\.png/png/' *`

Hope it helps.

Comment: Would be great with an added explanation for what the command does.

Comment: Homebrew has removed the ability to provide options so `--with-librsvg` is no longer valid see here https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/pull/36079

Answer (score 4):

Try [Apache Batik](http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/batik/tools/rasterizer.html).

```
java -jar batik-rasterizer.jar FILES
```

It also supports batch conversion and has many other useful options.

Answer (score 4):

You can also use [phantomjs](http://phantomjs.org/) to render the svg.  The advantage is that it renders it like a browser would since it's basically a headless WebKit.

Once you download it you need **phantomjs** (binary) and the **rasterizer.js** file from the examples folder.

```
phantomjs examples/rasterize.js Tiger.svg out.png
```

Comment: For reference, this can be installed with `brew cask install phantomjs`. In my install, the examples folder was located in the path `/usr/local/Caskroom/phantomjs/2.1.1/phantomjs-2.1.1-macosx/examples/`.

Comment: It's now `brew install --cask phantomjs`. Otherwise it still works great. It doesn't crop the image properly and it's quite slow but it's the only solution that supports embedded fonts.

Answer (score 2):

ImageMagick's convert command, using some other parameters, is what did it for me. Here's my batch Bash script solution that divides the task across multiple processes to make use of all your cores! Modify as needed.

batchConvertToSVG.sh (takes number of processes as argument):

```
end=$(( $1 - 1 ))
for i in `seq 0 $end`;
        do
            echo Spawning helper $i of $end
                ./convertToSvgHelper.sh $i $1 &
        done
```

convertToSvgHelper.sh:

```
n=$1
for file in ./*.svg; do
   filename=${file%.svg}
   echo converting file named $filename
   test $n -eq 0 && convert -format png -resize 74 -background transparent -density 600 $file $filename.png
   n=$((n+1))
   n=$((n%$2))
done
```

Answer (score 1):

I use this command on my linux. It should work for you as well.

```
mogrify +antialias -density 2000 -verbose -format png *.svg
```

I learned that without the "-density" argument, the bitmap would be very pixelized. Change the -density value to match your need.

Comment: Even with density, the conversion does not generate an image that is as sharp as a vector image. Try Apache Batik instead.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to checkout [svgexport](https://www.npmjs.com/package/svgexport):

```
svgexport input.svg output.png 64x
svgexport input.svg output.png 1024:1024
```

svgexport is a simple command-line tool and npm package that I made for exporting svg to png/jpeg. To install svgexport install npm, then run:

```
npm install -g svgexport
```

Answer (score 1):

I created a function based on @seb 's answer

```
function svg2png() {
    svgFile=$1;
    width=$2;

    if [[ -z `file ${svgFile} | grep 'Scalable Vector Graphics image'` ]]; then
        echo "file ${svgFile} type is not SVG";
        return 1;
    fi

    echo "file ${svgFile} type is SVG";

    if [[ -z ${width} ]]; then
        echo "width not specified, using width=1024 as default";
        width=1024;
    fi

    pngFile="$(echo ${svgFile} | sed "s/\.[s,S][v,V][g,G]/\.png/")";

    inkscape --export-type png --export-filename ${pngFile} -w ${width} ${svgFile};
}
```

add this into you `.bashrc` or `.zshrc` and execute

```
source .bashrc
# or
source .zshrc
```

Usage:
svg2png ./Documents/times_clocks.svg 2048

Answer (score 1):

Python package `cairosvg` works best for me.

```
cairosvg x.svg -o x.png
```

Install it by
`pip3 install cairosvg`

Comment: This is pretty useful. Not everyone is with nodejs environment, but Python environment is much easier to install.

Answer (score 1):

You can use svglib:

```
pip3 install svglib
```

Code:

```
from svglib.svglib import svg2rlg
from reportlab.graphics import renderPM

drawing = svg2rlg('input.svg')
renderPM.drawToFile(drawing, 'output.png', fmt='PNG')
```

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so I've found other answers somewhat interesting but not particularly awesome. I wanted to convert every single FontAwesome SVG to a 1920 wide png. But I also wanted to color grade the svg to match my branding. The cool thing about SVGs is that they are XML under the hood.

On macOS I used rsvg-convert command.

Open up the terminal (command + Space then type in terminal.

```bash
brew install librsvg
```

If you don't have [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/) you'll want to install it. It simplifies installing typical packages available on linux ... but without needing to find the appropriate .pkg files.

Extract the zip or just navigate to the directory wherever you have the folders.

Create a file called, **color.css** and place it in base directory you're working with.

For example, if you downloaded FontAwesome and extracted it in Downloads you'd cd ~/Downloads/fontawesome-pro-5.15.4-desktop/svgs

or whatever version you moved to.

I use nano -- it's easy for me. You can use any plain text editor though.

For FontAwesome SVGs they basically have an everything color, and for duotone icons they have SVGs with a class of .fa-primary and .fa-secondary.

```css
* { fill: #FAAF40; }
.fa-primary { fill: #FAAF40; }
.fa-secondary { fill: #AD731C; }
```

Open up the SVG you want to modify and see if it has special classes in it that you want to add color to that deviate from this example.

The first line says everything gets #FAAF40 if not specified;
The second line is the same ... so technically it's redundant and can go away but I kept it there for my personal reference.
The third line applies #AD731C; just to the fa-secondary CSS class.

```bash
find . -type f -name "*.svg" | xargs -I{} rsvg-convert -w 1920 --stylesheet=./color.css {} -o {}.png
```

This command does all of the magic once you have your color.css file. It looks a bit crazy to those unfamiliar with xargs ... but here's how it works.

`find . -type f - name "*.svg"` means look in the current directory for any **file** ending in **.svg**.

Then pipe that output to the xargs command.

xargs then takes that filename and passes it to the rsvg-convert command with arguments. the {} twice means that the filename is passed in twice. So replace {} in your head with whatever file it's going to fiddle with.

Best of luck!

Answer (score 0):

As commented previously ImageMagick does the trick. I just wanted to add a point for [GraphicsMagick](http://www.graphicsmagick.org/), an old fork of ImageMagick that has some improvements (and much less dependency bloat when installed via fink).

Answer (score 0):

You can perform a batch conversion on an entire folder of SVG files to PNG. I used Inkscape command line interface to produce png files with a width of 80px.

```
find ~/desktop/toconvert '*.svg' -exec /Applications/Inkscape.app/Contents/Resources/bin/inkscape -z -w 80 -e "{}".png "{}" \;
```

png will be saved with original name *.png

Answer (score 0):

[wkhtmltoimage](https://wkhtmltopdf.org/) (from project wkhtmltopdf) did this convert well:

```
wkhtmltoimage --zoom 2 foo.svg foo.png
```

`ImageMagick` renders CJK character as blank on my mac.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/813997)

Comment: @Blackwood fine, updated.

Answer (score 0):

I have started to put together a [tool](https://github.com/mountbuild/mouse) to provide a simplified interface to common actions.

You can convert an SVG to a PNG like this:

```
$ npm install @mountbuild/mouse -g
$ mouse convert input.svg -o output.png
```

This will create a new PNG for the SVG.

If nothing else check out the source and see how to write your own script to do this in JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

In 2024, I found the [resvg](https://github.com/RazrFalcon/resvg) project (written in Rust) to be highly efficient. I benchmarked it and found it faster than rsvg-convert on Apple Silicon M-series CPUs.

Combined with the also excellent [fd](https://github.com/sharkdp/fd), it becomes a one-liner to quickly convert a directory full of SVGs into PNGs of your desired size:

```shell
fd -t file -e svg -x resvg --height 512 {} {.}.png
```